# insert multiple records SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-edittext

I am creating EditText dynamically, I have to enter the values ​​in the column "IMPORTO_FATTURA" SQLite table.
But for every value must be created a new record .... how do I?
This is the code created so far.

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(FattureTable.NOME_FORNITORE, spinnerFornitori.getSelectedItem().toString());
if(lineare instanceof ViewGroup) {
    for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)lineare).getChildCount(); i++) {
        View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)lineare).getChildAt(i);
        if(nextChild instanceof LinearLayout) {
            View child = ((LinearLayout)nextChild).getChildAt(0);
            if(child instanceof EditText) {
                EditText et = (EditText)child;
                String value = et.getText().toString();                            
                cv.put(FattureTable.IMPORTO_FATTURA, value);                               
            }
        }
     }
}
 cv.put(FattureTable.IMPORTO_FATTURA, Importo.getText().toString());
....
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if by multiple values you mean text from multiple `EditText` fields or splitting one field into multiple results. Here's how to do both.

*Multiple edit texts*
The basic idea here is to just use a loop. If you're using a fixed number of edit texts the process is easier but not really that much different. In one case you loop over the contents of an `Array` or `List` (or hey `ArrayList`) containing the contents of all known `EditText`, the other you loop over the contents of a container view. For example

```
ArrayList<String> textFieldEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
textFieldEntries.put(editText1.getText().toString));
//add all values to this array . . .

databaseHandler.addValues(textFieldEntries);
```

The databaseHandler is a class (you don't need to do it this way but its much cleaner) that actually interacts with your database. The method addEntry could look something like

```
public void addEntry(ArrayList<String> entries){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    for(String text : entries){
        cv.put(key, text);
    }
    db.insert(TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

The basic idea is to collect all that you want to add first and then loop through the contents of that collection, add those values to the content values, and then insert that whole chunk of content at once.

*One view many values*

If you have one view that has a string entry that needs to be divided the idea would be the same as above only you would use `split` on the string and have it divide based on a set character (could be a space). This would give you a string array that you could then loop through in the same way as above.

If the splitting is more involved you could always jus make your own tokenizer class that would return an array of whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look over SQLite compiled statements;